# Как в одной ячейке таблицы html создать два столбца?

Tags: html, css

Помогите, пожалуйста! Как мне расположить текст в два столбика в одной ячейке в таблице html?

Comment: Вот: http://jsfiddle.net/HA3IK/cLbfn/ ...возможно, эти примеры помогут Вам разобраться.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Таблица состоит из столбцов и строк. Столбцы это вертикальные ряды, строки это горизонтальные ряды. Таблица из двух столбцов означает, что у вас должен быть один вертикальный ряд(строка) и два горизонтальных(столбцы). За строки в html отвечает тег tr, за столбцы тег td,  таким образом верстка двухстолбцовой таблицы выглядит как то так:

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>Столбец 1</td>
<td>Столбец 2</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Помещаете код выше в любую ячейку таблицы и получаете разбиение ячейки еще на две колонки.

Comment: Спасибо вам НAЗIK b Ridzhi  за подробные примеры! Все получилось!

Answer (score 7):

Внутрь ячейки вставить еще одну таблицу из двух столбцов.

Comment: А по подробней можно?

Comment: Куда уж подробней? `<td><table>...</table></td>`

Comment: А как понять таблицу из двух столбцов? Ведь я и ищу способ создать два столбца в одной ячейки!

Answer (score 2):

Еще можешь использовать программу Adobe Dreamwear CS5 или поздней версии для создания готовых таблиц и другие элементы а также можешь смотреть код и учится